# zoom in automatically in map svg

Tags: javascript, svg, svgpanzoom

I have a map in SVG format.
I wanted to integrate features zoom and zoom out.
I used the library svg-pan-zoom, it served me very well but I did not find a feature that allows me to zoom in on a specific area automatically.
The map contains all the departments of Europe and I want that when I select certain criteria an automatic zoom this done on specific areas.
Does svg-pan-zoom allow me to do that if no do you know of another library that meets the needs?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with `svgpanzoom`. But in general you can use the `viewBox` attribute to zoom to a specific area of your SVG.

Consider the following example. It's a simple SVG with 3 rectangles.

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="0 0 200 200">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
  <rect x="100" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
  <rect x="110" y="60" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

Now if you want to zoom into the green rectangle, just add the `viewBox` attribute to the x/y/width/height of the area you want to zoom to. The green rectangle is 100/50/50/50. See it live here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/eyaggG

```
<svg width="200" height="200" viewBox="100 50 50 50">
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="red" />
  <rect x="100" y="50" width="50" height="50" fill="green" />
  <rect x="110" y="60" width="30" height="30" fill="blue" />
</svg>
```

I hope this will help you

Comment: Thank you Alex,
I use map svg with path to draw my object SVG
exemple : https://www.amcharts.com/svg-maps/?map=franceDepartments